# How can I update subscription product and price?

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

My test user has already a subscription, and I want to change this on my backend. I've tried setting the metadata, containing the new product and price id's , but without luck.

```
        var options = new SubscriptionUpdateOptions
        {
            ProrationBehavior = "create_prorations",
            Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
              {
                { "product_id", product.Id },
                { "price_id", price.Id },
              },
        };

        var updateResult = subscriptionService.Update(subscription.Id, options);
```

The request is OK, but nothing changes.

Any tips from someone who is doing this?

Comment: the respose is just okay ? can you copy paste updateResult here ? maybe some messages can Help !

Answer (score 0):

First let's try to clarify the problem. You stated

> I've tried setting the metadata, containing the new product and price id's , but without luck.

but `metadata` is defined in the Stripe docs for Subscriptions as a simple series of key:value pairs.

> **metadata:** Set of key-value pairs that you can attach to an object. This can be useful for storing additional information about the object in a structured format. Individual keys can be unset by posting an empty value to them.

You can see an example of how this is updated in the [API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update?lang=dotnet).

If you want to update the actual product and price in the subscription, you will need to pass the revised set of items to the [Update API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update?lang=dotnet#update_subscription-items) as an array of hashes.

All Stripe code snippets can be viewed in C# (often labeled as .NET).